# Symfony2 Multiple Twig Extensions

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.1

Is it possible to create multiple Twig extension ? Because when I add a second one, I get the error message that the first extension method is not existing in the second extension.

Here is how my extension are defined in services.xml :

```
<service id="acme.extension.view_helper" class="FLS\AcmeBundle\Extension\ViewHelperExtension">
        <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
        <tag name="twig.extension" />
 </service>

<service id="acme.extension.stats_helper" class="FLS\AcmeBundle\Extension\StatsExtension">
        <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
        <tag name="twig.extension" />
</service>
```

And here is the error message :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   FLS\AcmeBundle\Extension\StatsExtension::findTask() in
>   F:\www\AcmeBundle\app\cache\dev\twig\fe\fd\4ff31bf8efd0669b6d0b2a14ba11.php
>   on line 232

The findTask method is defined in ViewHelperExtension.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share your ViewHelperExtension and StatsExtension code please

Comment: Same problem encountered here. The service definitions are Ok. Seems to be the case of a strange behavior: while defining two service extensions only the last defined one is available. This issue can be related to Twig

Comment: I have the same problem but only if the servises are in the same bundle

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: TL;DR. Yes. It is possible**

I just had this issue right now. In my case, the reason for this was that I started with the same boilerplate for both extensions and the `getName()` function inside each was returning the same name.

Once I changed the name that function returns on each extension both extensions were added. I assume something like the following would work:

In *src/AppBundle/Twig/AppBundleFooExtension.php*

```
/* ... */
public function getName()
{
    return 'appbundle_foo_extension';
}
/* ... */
```

In *src/AppBundle/Twig/AppBundleBarExtension.php*

```
/* ... */
public function getName()
{
    return 'appbundle_bar_extension';
}
/* ... */
```

Answer (score 0):

I use several twig extension in my project and everything is ok. Your services.xml containes service tags? 
`<services>
   // Services definition
</services>` 
Looks like second service override first.

Article [How to write a custom Twig Extension](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html)

Comment: Strangely, everything I had to do in the services.xml file is to move the order of my services definitions. For example, I inserted between the two definitions of my extensions another service definition for a FormHandler and the override problem disappeared...